# Vuejs app showing Invalid host header error loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nginx, nginx-config

I was running a vuejs app on its own dev server, now I can access the site by public IP of machine, But after pointing it with a domain using nginx its showing an error loop in console

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhI7m.png)

Invalid Host header
[WDS] Disconnected!

Due to this the script,style injection and auto reload not working.

***config of dev server***

```
dev: {
  assetsSubDirectory: "static",
  assetsPublicPath: "/",
  disableHostCheck: true,
  host: "0.0.0.0", // '192.168.2.39',//can be overwritten by 
  process.env.HOST
  port: 8080,
  autoOpenBrowser: false,
  errorOverlay: false,
  notifyOnErrors: false,
  poll: true, 
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  cacheBusting: true,
  cssSourceMap: true
},
```

***nginx config for the domain***

```
server
{
  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name prajin.prakash.com;
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I believe you need to change `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes there are other nodes already there so be sure to attach this at the root - e.g., pwa: {}, devServer: {} -- I missed missed that at first...  Seeing this made me realize, duh... lol

Comment: may result in security vulnerabilities - see the answer bellow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116155/3467734)

Comment: I'd upvote more if I could. The docs around vue.configs.js are hard to find. devServer: proxy is another very useful one.

Comment: this does not work anymore in webpack-dev-server v >= 4, see the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736358/8216911)

Answer (score 25):

Generally it is not recommended to `disableHostCheck: true` (as it may result in security issues), unless you understand and accept the risks.

Please instead try setting webpack config as follows:

In app root in vue.config.js add

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    public: 'subdomain.domain.ext:port'
  }
};
```

NB: for apps running on vuejs + nginx

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, as it explains the HOW and the WHY

Comment: I'd be happy with this answer, if it didn't also result in an invalid host error.

Answer (score 23):

In webpack-dev-server@v3:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
};
```

in webpack-dev-server@v4, the option `disableHostCheck` has been removed, use `allowedHosts` instead:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    // 'auto' | 'all' [string] here
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
};
```

see documentation here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts

Answer (score 11):

### Feb, 2022 Update:

Create **`vue.config.js`** just under the project root directory:

[image]

Then, paste this code below to **`vue.config.js`**:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

****Don't forget to restart the server otherwise the change is not reflected.***

Answer (score 7):

###### "vue": "^3.2.13",

###### "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: "all",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change vue.config.js file. It is present in your project root (next to package.json).

```
v3:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
};
```

```
v4:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: "all",
  },
};
```

Ref: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that was due to my mistake, I forgot to add disableHostCheck variable in

> build/webpack.dev.conf.js

Adding the following solved my issue

```
disableHostCheck: config.dev.disableHostCheck,
```

Answer (score 2):

My config in: projects/vue-try/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/options.js

#### line 130+

devServer: {
disableHostCheck: true,
host : '0.0.0.0',
https: false
}

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to change the nginX configuration like this

```
server {
  server_name prajin.prakash.com;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  }
}
```

### EDIT:

Added separate proxying for WebSocket and normal requests.

Comment: after adding this the site won't work raising an error.
      504 Gateway Time-out
      nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Comment: `disableHostCheck: true,`  fixed my issue ,anyway thanks for your replay..