# Invalid Host header Vue3

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vps

Just uploaded project files and configured nginx. Everything seems working fine without any errors. However, whenever I visit the domain I see the message 'Invalid Host header'. Followed by many solutions with vue.config.js file, none of them did a trick. The file is created in the same root level with package.json and src folder. Here's how it looks:

```
module.exports = {
   devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true
    }
};
```

Also, tried this solution:

```
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: [
      'yourdomain.com'
    ]
}
```

Here's the part from the /sites-available file

```
server {
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try everything from this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084089/vuejs-app-showing-invalid-host-header-error-loop

Comment: Yap. Tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons the project always been running on 8081 port, just had to check logs more carefully. Updating proxy_pass solved it

Comment: What did you update proxy_pass to?

Comment: Instead of http://localhost:8080 I changed it to http://localhost:8081. Take a look at your logs to check on which port your project is running and then set proxy_pass.